# iTunes Connect and Bundle ID from another developer account

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I used the developer account of my company to create a **BundleID**, configure APNS and set development and distribution provisioning profiles. I created an application and compiled it with the provisioning of my company. Everything works fine.

So now my customer wants to submit the app with its own itunes connect account.

I may be wrong but the process to submit a new app has changed (since the last time i used it ^^).

In the first screen, you need to fill the **App Name**, the **SKU Number** and the **Bundle ID**.

This is a simple interrogation : Does my customer only needs to create the same BundleID to make it correct (understand submission and apns purpose) ? Or does he needs to setup everything and do i need to rebuild the app ?

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App name & bundle ID are unique. You can't reuse the bundle ID or App name. So if you want to move the app to your customer's account you've to take a new bundle id & App name.. (And you'll need new certificates to sign it)

Comment: precison, i don't want to move an app